# print key into txt file

Tags: python, printing

So I am working on a script to generate serialnumbers for a product. I want to make a txt file where I the script prints the generated key. somehow it cant print in there but I don't know what I need to changes about it.

```
key = Key('aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-1111')

fh = open('key.txt')

fh.write(Key)
```

Comment: What is the `Key` class? Does it have a method for representing a string?

It's often more sensible to use a context manager to handle setup and teardown of files.

`with open('key.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(key, file=f)`

If the `Key` class is your own, you can add a \_\_str\_\_ method to print out the key string you need.

Comment: In 'Key' i have few commands so it can create serialnumbers with the parameters I've set inside the key class @hemmelig

Comment: Can you add this class to your question? Doesn't need to have all the details, but it will help me properly answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on your response, I've mocked up the `Key` class as follows. Without more information, it's not possible to give you a definitive answer, but hopefully this helps!

```py
class Key:
    def __init__(self, serial):
        self.serial = serial

    def process_serial(self):
        # Your processing here
        ...
        return processed_serial  # This should be a string
```

Then to write to file, you can do:

```py
key = Key('aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-1111')

with open('key.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(key.process_serial())
```

Alternatively, you can add a `__str__` method to your class, which will specify what happens when you call the Python builtin `str` on your object.

```py
class Key:
    def __init__(self, serial):
        self.serial = serial

    def __str__(self):
        out = ...  # construct what you want to write to file
        return out
```

Giving:

```py
key = Key('aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-1111')

with open('key.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(key))
```

You might also consider adding this as a method to your Key class

```
class Key:
    __init__(self, serial):
        self.serial = serial

    def process_serial(self):
        # Your processing here
        ...
        return processed_serial  # This should be a string

    def write(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.process_serial)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. still doesnt work. idk why but i will just leave a link where you can find the whole script: [https://gist.github.com/howCodeORG/4b456d334a85b516c0860b7495ff9d18 ]

Comment: Copying the code from your gist and running the 2nd example for writing (using `str(key)`) works fine for me. It creates a file called key.txt and for the example input text I get `AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD:1111:Invalid`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: well ye it is what i want but it prints exactly 'AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-1111:Invalid' not the generated key

Comment: Because if you pass in a string that is not empty, a key is never generated? It is behaving exactly as it should do.

If you do not provide an input, then a valid key is generated by randomly building keys until you create one with a total char score adds up to 1772. If you provide an input, it is just set as the key, nothing is generated. You need to clarify what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
key = "Key('aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-1111')"
fh = open('key.txt', "w")
fh.write(key)
```

To generate a text file that doesn't already exist you need to use `"w"` .

Comment: @Simon Schiller If the answer solved your problem you can accept it with the checkmark Icon on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```py
key = Key('aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-1111')
    
with open('key.txt', 'w') as fh: 
    fh.write(key)
```

Hope that Helps!
Note: it must be in the `with ...` so it writes, if its not there the file is considered as closed.

Comment: well it creates the file somehow but still get this error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Key

Comment: Just change `fh.write(key)` to `fh.write(str(key))`. Hope that helps!